# Debuging CRM 2011 plugin with Plugin Profiler shows exception message "Download the details and load with Plug-in Profiler"

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011

In our current CRM plugin development we're trying to debug a plugin.
For this we're using the Plugin Profiler as described [here](http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2013/03/debugging-crm-2011-plugins-with-the-plugin-profiler.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20typepad/sonoma%20%28Sonoma%20Partners%20Microsoft%20CRM%20Blog%29).
When we finally step through our code and run into the exception we expect, the message is "Download the details and load with Plug-in Profiler"

Isn't the whole purpose of the (quite tedious) process that this message would be filled in by the Plugin Profiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen if you are still profiling your plugin while running the debug trace.
In the **Plugin Registration Tool**, make sure you click `stop profiling` before you click `debug` to rerun your profiled trace.